# Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this existing project ASP.NET web application which is using .NET Framework 4.x and Entity Framework 6. For Entity Framework 6, it uses ADO.NET Entity Data Model > EF Designer from database.

The project could not compile due to one error. In the error list, it shows that the error is from `Model.tt` on the first line. `<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>`.

The error description is *"Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

By the way, I also notice that initially there are some errors *"The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*. I notice that `Model.cs` (the file under `Model.tt`) is empty. I have to manually copy the code from the repository to this class. After that, there is no more of this error *"The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*.

Now I only stuck with one error *"Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."* I am stuck with this as I am not so sure how to debug further.

This `Model.tt` class is auto generated using ADO.NET Entity Data Model > EF Designer from database.

Comment: This `Model.tt` class is auto generated using `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` > `EF Designer from database`

Comment: Found the issue already. Delete the hidden .vs folder. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: In reviewing for reopen I noticed the OP had resolved his own issue here and it doesn't seem very useful any more. Voting to delete.

Comment: Also was reviewing for reopen and feel like the root cause was an EF code generation issue, not really a null reference issue, and others could benefit from the solution. I propose leaving it alone or adding an answer with the solution: Delete the .vs folder.